# Why can't I resize a canvas using the layout constraints?

Tags: java, javafx

Have an AnchorPane, then put a Canvas. Set the canvas' layout constraints (top, left, right, bottom). Technically, the canvas should resize if the AnchorPane resizes. But it does not. If you use something like a button instead of a canvas, it works.

Why can't I resize a canvas using the layout constraints?

Comment: Make sure the canvas is resizable. Also, have you tried redrawing the canvas as your pane grows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Canvas is a direct sub-class of `Node` and does not override `Node.isResizable()`, so the default is taken:

```
public boolean isResizable() {
    return false;
}
```

This is just a technical explanation why parent layout containers will skip the Canvas during layout calculations.

The other consideration is that `Canvas` and "normal" JavaFX `Node`s internally work completely different.

During every layout pass (`Parent.layoutChildren()` and `Node.autosize()`) the layout of a `Node` gets recalculated to always reflect the correct state. There are many other factors (cache hint, optimizations, visible state, managed state, ...) that are getting into play, but this is the very basic concept here.

The `Canvas` on the other hand is a `Node` that paints all its "children" onto a whiteboard via the `GraphicsContext` and is done. No layouting, no autosize. So this is blazing fast  (after the initial painting) and if you change this you should know what you are doing and why you are doing this, because making a `Canvas` resizable strips many benefits away.

But there is a very nice and fast example how to create a resizable canvas: http://fxexperience.com/2014/05/resizable-grid-using-canvas/